# Can't run Pitivi after installation getting flatpak error

Tags: ubuntu, flatpak

I have installed the Pitivi video editor as the instruction given [here](http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/Install_with_flatpak) , but I can't launch "Pitivi" from application menu, and even it is not listed there.

When I run the `flatpak list` it show the `org.pitivi.Pitivi` as installed app, but when I tried to run it as `flatpak run org.pitivi.Pitivi` it gives the following error:

`error: runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.22 not installed`
My question is how I can install Flatpak [runtime](http://flatpak.org/runtimes.html), Will installing that missing runtime solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it out on Fedora 25 (currently still beta) and had no issues (master-branch). - I saved the output of curl to a file called `pitivi-flatpak` and then ran `./pitivi-flatpak --branch=master --update`. That downloaded all the dependencies and now I can run the program by using `./pitivi-flatpak`. Hope that helps you to narrow down your issue!

Comment: Do we need to start it from terminal always ? I mean run ./pitivi-flatpak.
As in the [documentation][1] I thought it should come to launcher when we search for the name Pitivi

[1]: http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/Install_with_flatpak#Running_Pitivi

Comment: It did create a shortcut for me

Answer (score 1):

You can install the GNOME runtime as follows:

```
$ flatpak remote-add --from gnome https://sdk.gnome.org/gnome.flatpakrepo
$ flatpak install gnome org.gnome.Platform//3.22
```